# Points in intersection

Tags: matrices

Given a matrix[nrows][ncols], and suppose it represents a terrain, like:
(0,0) (1,0) (2,0)..
(0,1).....
or a cartesian plan...

and I have 2 points, both choosen by the user...
How can I know which points the line that cross the two points are intersecting?

example, considering cartesian plan:
point 0: (1,0) , point 2: (5,4), the points inside the intersection is: (2,1),(3,2),(4,3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this by hand, then suppose you have points $(1,0),(5,4)$,then the slope of the points will be $\frac{4-0}{5-1}=\frac44=\frac11$. Then for every "1" you add to the y-value, you add "1" to the x-value.

More generally, you will always have a slope between two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. First you want the slope $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$. Then you want to reduce that fraction as much as possible without using decimals. Suppose that both the numerator and denominator divide by a factor of $d$. Then you will have a new slope of $\frac{(y_2-y_1)/d}{(x_2-x_1)/d}=\frac{y_d}{x_d}$. Now for any integer $n$, all your intersection points will be defined by $(x_1+nx_d,y_1+ny_d)$

Suppose you had points $(3,0)$ and $(12,12)$, then your slope is $12/9$ which reduces to $4/3$, so your $y_d=4$ and $x_d=3$. Now for any integer $n$, all your points are defined by $(3+3n,0+4n)$

Comment: Hello, I was studying this idea, and i cross with a point like (4,1) and (12,12), and yd = 11 , xd = 8, so it wouldnt be possible, 
another example would be: (3,0) and (9,9), yd = 3 and xd = 2, so (3 + 2n,0+3n), for n = 1 => (5,3), it wouldnt cross (4,2) first?

Comment: @ViperAlpha For a line segment drawn through $(4,1)$ and $(12,12)$, no other points are intersected in between. In the case for $(3,0)$ and $(9,9)$, only the points $(5,3)$ and $(7,6)$ are intersected, not $(4,2)$

Comment: Got it... thank you very much!